# Entity Framework Core Global Dynamic Query Filter

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

we are using ef core 3.1
And we want to use  dynamic query filter,
I tried sample implementation but did not work correctly we expected, filtering always same tenant id,i tried to explain at below

```cs
 public class TestDbContext : DbContext
    {
      
        public DbSet<TenantUser> TenantUsers { get; set; }
      

        private readonly ITenantProvider _tenantProvider;

        private Guid? TenantId => _tenantProvider.TenantId;

        public TestDbContext (DbContextOptions<TestDbContext > options, ITenantProvider tenantProvider) : base(options)
        {
               _tenantProvider = tenantProvider;
        }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<TenantUser>()
                .HasQueryFilter(p => EF.Property<Guid>(p, "TenantId") == TenantId);
        }

    }
```

**ITenantProvider** returns TenantId from HttpContext headers

this code filtering always same tenant id from coming first request

Update:

```
 public class TenantProvider : ITenantProvider
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public TenantProvider(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public Guid? TenantId
        {
            get
            {
                if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(HeaderNames.TenantId, out var tenantId) &&
                    Guid.TryParse(tenantId, out Guid parsedTenantId))
                {
                    return parsedTenantId;
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

For example
First Request TenantId = 60000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
This filter => 60000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

Second Request TenantId = 10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
This filter =>  60000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

Comment: `but did not work` isn't a problem description. And `this code filtering always same tenant id from coming first request` sounds like the filter *did* work. It's `_tenantProvider.TenantId` that returns the same ID every time. Or you use the same DbContext every time (very bad idea) which means you always use the value stored in the `TenantId` field

Comment: Post the `ITenantProvider` code. This doesn't seem to be about EF Core

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos added

Comment: Looks correct. Changing visibility of `TenantId` to `public` will not help?

Comment: But are you using a *different* DbContext instance? Or a singleton/pooled one?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no signleton it is scoped , no pooled normal dbcontext register method

Comment: https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/building-asp-net-core-and-ef-core-multi-tenant-apps-part1-the-database/

Answer (score 3):

You should also implement a custom IModelCacheKeyFactory

```
public class MyModelCacheKeyFactory : IModelCacheKeyFactory
{
    public object Create(DbContext context)
    {
        if (context is TestDbContext testDbContext)
        {
            return (context.GetType(), testDbContext.TenantId);
        }
        return context.GetType();
    }
}
```

And then, you need to replace like this

```
var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TestDbContext>();

builder.ReplaceService<IModelCacheKeyFactory, MyModelCacheKeyFactory>();

var context = new TestDbContext(builder.Options);
```

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.imodelcachekeyfactory

Comment: This works for me!

[Alternating between multiple models with the same DbContext type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/dynamic-model)

Answer (score 2):

We tried something similar like that a few years ago. Main problem is here that OnModelCreating method only triggered once. So HasQueryFilter works once and gets the current tenant id from provider and it applies to all queries the same tenant id.